# Create reset password link with data and send to email ASP.NET Core Web-API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

In my old project MVC core, I did a link for recover password such way:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
        }

        var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
        MailSend emailService = new MailSend();
        await emailService.SendResetPassword(model.Email, 
            $"for reset password open a link: <a href='{callbackUrl}'>link</a>");
        return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
    }
```

Question is about this section: `var callbackUrl = Url.Action`

Now I have API-controller for this method, not MVC controller. How I can create this link with data for API controller for this address?

```
[Route("api/account/reset-password")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do this, in the first place. An API typically returns something like JSON, which a web user will be unable to utilize. If you send the user directly to the API endpoint, they'll essentially be dead-ended with a response that makes no sense to them in the context of browsing the web.

If the logic for doing the password reset is contained in the API endpoint, then you should have a regular MVC action that you send the user to. This action will then interact with the API on the user's behalf, and ultimately return a HTML they can actually interact with.